# Visual studio debug values changing when looking into them?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, unit-testing

So i've been writing some unit tests, and there's one test that fails that shouldn't fail, so I started debugging the test. I looked through the properties and after the debugging was finished, the test passed. weird? So, I ran the test again, and it failed again.

Turns out, the properties(in this case .Selected of an listview-item) actually changed when I looked into it, but it didn't when I don't.....

Here's a video I made to show this weird issue.

https://youtu.be/OsUhh-MlOoU

Comment: Is `SelectedItem` in your video an observable collection? May be it is because it takes time to fill values?

Comment: I don't know, but it definitely isn't time based. i could wait an hour and the selected item count is still 0. the second i click the expand arrow to see details, it fills

Comment: Your properties has side-effects. The SelectedItems property is filled with data after expanding the debug view on its parent/owning object, one of the other properties, when evaluated, also changes the data behind SelectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) for SelectedItems has this to say:

> The SelectedItems property will not contain any items if the property is accessed before the ListView handle is created.

Since you're in a test method I would assume you don't actually show the form, nor the listview, on the screen which would require a handle. As such, the listview doesn't get a handle until you force it to.

The act of expanding the listview object in the debug inspector makes the SelectedItems property suddenly contain the element after all which indicates to me that one of the other properties on the ListView type has a side-effect of triggering this creation of a handle.

Here's a small example that demonstrates a similar situation:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine(x.GoodProperty); // place a breakpoint on this line
    Console.WriteLine(x.BadProperty);
    Console.WriteLine(x.GoodProperty);
}

public class Test
{
    public int GoodProperty { get; set; }
    public int BadProperty => GoodProperty++;
}
```

If you place a breakpoint on the indicated line, then use your mouse to just mouse over the `x.GoodProperty` expression in the same line, you'll get 0. You can do this over and over again and it still produces 0.

However, every time you mouse over the `x.BadProperty` expression, `x.GoodProperty` will also increase by 1.

The exact same thing would happen if you mouse over `x` and expand it to show all properties. Depending on whether `GoodProperty` or `BadProperty` will evaluate first when you expand `x`, the expanded view may or may not show a changed `GoodProperty` value.

Comment: You should change your code because you're involving the GUI code of .NET in your tests and you should focus on the business logic you've written yourself. This test shows that you fall prey to assumptions and rules regarding how a GUI works which is completely orthogonal to the code you want to test. As such you should split up your code to manipulate your own data structures and test agains that, and then have a adapter/binding layer that integrates your data structures with the GUI.